# Zend multiple directories and MVC routing

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, url-routing

I'm building my first personal website using Zend 1.11. To create the directory structure I've used the zf script that comes with the framework. I can use the same script to create controllers/views like so:

```
/home
/contact
/blog
/about
```

Yet where I've come unstuck is trying to encompass multiple directories e.g.

```
/contact/address
/about/cv/workhistory
```

...I just get an error saying the content cannot be found. There is no model, just a controller (route?) and a view. I've tried adding the desired directory structure when I use zf but this results in an error e.g.

```
zf create controller about/cv/workhistory
```

Is this even possible in MVC or does it show a lack of understanding of what MVC is on my part?  Thanks in advance for any help/tips/pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok you've created some controllers. Now it looks as though you want to add some functions to your controllers.
In order to do */contact/address* it would be appropriate to have the addressAction() inside your ContactController().

A *controller* is a group of *actions* (read METHODS). When you built your application 2 controllers were built with it, one of them was the *IndexController()* that also gave you your first action *indexAction()* and your first view *index.phtml* located at */application/views/scripts/index*:

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }


}
```

Zend Framework implements the MVC paradigm with actual Models, Views and Controllers. In the controllers are your actions grab data and prepare it to be viewed.

Go ahead and do yourself a favor and run through some tutorials, here are some suggestions.
[Rob Allens ZF 1.11 tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/)
[Zend Framework Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)
The naming conventions are important to understand and can be found at:
[Zend Framework Naming conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! It literally just clicked (having re-read the tutorials you sent). All that was missing was a custom route to map requests to controller/action pairs and it's working now.